# No overload for method 'query' takes 5 arguments salesforce

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am connecting with salesforce api, I have imported Salesforce enterprise Wsdl to my project.

I can authenticate user but I am having Problem while querying records, I'm not sure what else I am missing and how to solve this

> No overload for method 'query' takes 5 arguments

```
//create SOQL query statement
string query = "SELECT Name, AccountNumber, BillingState FROM Account WHERE BillingState = 'CA'";

enterprise.QueryResult result = queryClient.query(
                header, //sessionheader
                null, //queryoptions
                null, //mruheader
                null, //packageversion
                query);

//cast query results
IEnumerable<enterprise.Account> accountList = result.records.Cast<enterprise.Account>();

//show results
foreach (var account in accountList)
{
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Account Name: {0}", account.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to difference in number of *parameters* pass in ***definition*** of method and ***calling***. You have passed `5` *parameters* to the `query` method and in definition may be different *parameters* count. Check the `query` method *parameters* count and then pass correct count of *parameters* when calling.

Comment: Thank you for the hint :)
i was passing 5 arguments, while method was taking 6, now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass to much parameters to the method.

Hover on the method, press F12 and look at the number of arguments the method expects, Then solve your problem accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the hint :)
i was passing 5 arguments, while method was taking 6, now it worked.