# c# "No overload for method 'Load' takes '1' arguments"

Tags: c#

Getting the CS1501 error "No overload for method 'Load' takes '1' arguments" and it is driving me insane because I have looked for a solution all over internet but cannot find any. So I ask here now, and hopefully recieve a solution that works.

PPSerialization:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class PPSerialization {

    public static BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    public static void Save(string saveTag, object obj) {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        string temp = System.Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(saveTag, temp);
    }

    public static object Load(string saveTag, object obj) {
        string temp = PlayerPrefs.GetString(saveTag);
        if (temp == string.Empty) {
            return null;
        }
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(temp));
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

GameInformation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameInformation : MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
    public static BaseEquipment EquipmentOne { get; set; }

    public static string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public static BaseCharacterClass PlayerClass { get; set; }
    public static int PlayerLevel { get; set; }
    public static int Health { get; set; }
    public static int Stamina { get; set; }
    public static int Strength { get; set; }
    public static int Intelligence { get; set; }
}
```

Save_Info:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Save_Info
{

    public static void SaveAllInfo() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("PLAYERNAME", GameInformation.PlayerName);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PLAYERLEVEL", GameInformation.PlayerLevel);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HEALTH", GameInformation.Health);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("STAMINA", GameInformation.Stamina);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("STRENGTH", GameInformation.Strength);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("INTELLIGENCE", GameInformation.Intelligence);

        if (GameInformation.EquipmentOne != null)
        {
            PPSerialization.Save("EQUIPMENTITEM1", GameInformation.EquipmentOne);
        }
        Debug.Log("SAVED");
    }
}
```

Load_Info:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Load_Info
{

    public static void LoadAllInfo()
    {
        GameInformation.PlayerName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PLAYERNAME");
        GameInformation.PlayerLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PLAYERLEVEL");
        GameInformation.Health = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HEALTH");
        GameInformation.Stamina = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("STAMINA");
        GameInformation.Strength = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("STRENGTH");
        GameInformation.Intelligence = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("INTELLIGENCE");

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("EQUIPMENTITEM1") != null)
        {
            GameInformation.EquipmentOne = (BaseEquipment)PPSerialization.Load("EQUIPMENTITEM1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static object Load(string saveTag, object obj) {`  is expecting a string and an object yet in your last line of code `(BaseEquipment)PPSerialization.Load("EQUIPMENTITEM1");`  you only send in a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No overload for method 'query' takes 5 arguments salesforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294490/no-overload-for-method-query-takes-5-arguments-salesforce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have method Load with 2 parameters

```
public static object Load(string saveTag, object obj) {
    string temp = PlayerPrefs.GetString(saveTag);
    if (temp == string.Empty) {
        return null;
    }
```

But you try to call it only with 1 paramert

```
 GameInformation.EquipmentOne = (BaseEquipment)PPSerialization.Load("EQUIPMENTITEM1");
```

Change your Load method like this :

```
public static object Load(string saveTag) {
        string temp = PlayerPrefs.GetString(saveTag);
        if (temp == string.Empty) {
            return null;
        }
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(temp));
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
```

Comment: I am following a tutorial and I wrote exactly what he wrote, and it works for him. So there is something going on. What would you like to add to the code?

Comment: Yeah I am stupid as Always. I didn't write exactly what he wrote. He never added the "object obj" to it. Thank you for the answer!