# How to solve "No overload for method, takes 0 arguments?" error

Tags: c#

In my simple producer/consumer multi threading project I am using a custom queue collection. I defined my `TryDequeue` like this...

```
public bool TryDequeue(out F data)
{
    data = default(F);
    bool success = false;
    lock (_queueLock)
    {
        if (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            data = _queue.Dequeue();
            success = true;
            count--;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

And when I try this...

```
private static void Consumer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        string item = null;
        lock (sharedQueue)
        {
            while (sharedQueue.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait(sharedQueue);
            item = sharedQueue.TryDequeue();
        }

    Console.WriteLine("Consuming item: {0}", item);
    }
}
```

which is a second thread, I get this error:

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'TryDequeue' takes 0 arguments
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your method has one argument `data` that you need to pass in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No overload for method 'query' takes 5 arguments salesforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294490/no-overload-for-method-query-takes-5-arguments-salesforce)

Comment: Also you really should create separate objects to use as locks instead of `lock(sharedQueue)`.  [_Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        string item = null;
        lock (sharedQueue)
        {
            while (sharedQueue.Count == 0)
                Monitor.Wait(sharedQueue);

            if(sharedQueue.TryDequeue(out item)) //succes!
               ...
            else                                 //something went wrong
               ...
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Consuming item: {0}", item);
    }
```

Your method returns a `bool`, you need to put your item together with the `out` keyword between the parenthesis. Right now you are not passing the expected `out F data` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`item = sharedQueue.TryDequeue();` is the culprit. `TryDequeue()` needs an *argument*.

Would `sharedQueue.TryDequeue(out item);` work? That seems to be what you need to do.